# vim keep autocomplete popup

Tags: c, vim

Together with ctags, I can complete functions with `<C-x><C-o>`and their arguments will pop up, like so:

[image: vim complete screenshot1]

However once I start typing an argument, the popup goes away:

[image: vim complete screenshot1]

Is there anyway I can keep the popup. (e.g until pressing another key combination, or just Enter.)

Answer (score 2):

What I suppose you are seeing is the function prototype added as a convenience by the tags completion (like other completions showing the originating file). The completion itself (and what gets inserted) is only about the function name itself.

Vim's completion menu is very generic; it does not handle function arguments like most IDEs now do.

Some completions can show extra information (like JavaDocs) in the preview window when `'completeopt'` contains `preview`.

There may be (languge-specific) plugins that enable the functionality you want, though, but I'm not aware of one.